# Why am I getting OutOfMemoryError compilation error in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, lift

I am working on a Lift project and trying to compile it with `scala:cc` and the scala compilation server  using the jvm args:

```
-Xmx1024m  -Xss20m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

The error also occurs with the jvm args:

```
-Xmx1024m  -Xss20m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

The result is:

```
[INFO] Compiling 16 source files to /Users/axaluss/IdeaProjects/trunk/Team_Skynet/target/classes at 1299141180948
[ERROR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.typeRef(Types.scala:2503)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.typeRef(SymbolTable.scala:13)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:2828)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:3209)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:3085)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:2849)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$AsSeenFromMap.apply(Types.scala:3209)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.asSeenFrom(Types.scala:507)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.computeMemberType(Types.scala:531)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$MethodSymbol.typeAsMemberOf(Symbols.scala:1774)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.memberType(Types.scala:522)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.findMember(Types.scala:858)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.nonPrivateMembers(Types.scala:453)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub0$1(Types.scala:4919)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub0$1(Types.scala:4873)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub(Types.scala:4943)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.lub(SymbolTable.scala:13)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lubsym$1(Types.scala:4901)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$$anonfun$38.apply(Types.scala:4924)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$$anonfun$38.apply(Types.scala:4919)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub0$1(Types.scala:4919)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub(Types.scala:4943)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.lub(SymbolTable.scala:13)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.lub(Types.scala:4863)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.lub(SymbolTable.scala:13)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$class.solveOne$1(Types.scala:4675)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(Types.scala:4684)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(Types.scala:4683)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
[ERROR] error: fatal error (server aborted): Java heap space
[ERROR] one error found
```

How can I solve this problem?
I dont know what is causing this error and found anything on Google except increasing the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you have to increase `mx`. One problem Scala *does* have is its big memory consumption. With the widespread adoption of 64 bits CPUs and server OS, and the current surge in adoption of 64 bits desktop OS, I expect it won't be critical much longer.

Comment: one gigabyte is not enough?!!

Comment: 2 GB xmx is not enough. it is compiling several minutes and fails in out of memory error.

Comment: @axaluss Well, then it's probably something else. Perhaps you have complex or large `match` statements? These are known to be vulnerable to exponential memory complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with setting some debugging on the compiler to try to find out where this stems from: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scalac.html